# Unexplained WordPress max RAM usage

Tags: php, wordpress, imap, litespeed

I have a simple Wordpress (4.9.6) website on shared litespeed hosting + cloudlfare + wp fastest cache plugin and 1GB RAM, php 7.2 (I tried different php versions but no improvement found). I also have maybe 15 email accounts and lots of email in the inbox, but I usually send ~20-50 emails/day using mozilla thunderbird. The RAM usage is high does not matter am I logged in the wp or not. There is no huge users activity, maybe 50 visitors / day. I have tried different things. Disabled lot's of non-major plugins. In cPanel there is only 1 cronjob which is softaculous backup once a day. Website is scanned from malware and has iThemes security plugin installed. Website performance is normal I think: http://prntscr.com/jjla8m Only negative aspects I find is google fonts requests: http://prntscr.com/jjlamj

The hosting provider said: "The process admin-ajax.php and lots of emails are consuming all of the RAM". As I supose, the emails sitting in the inbox does not consume RAM (or does it?) and I am only sending max 50 emails/day. The other thing I found about admin-ajax.php is the plugin called "Heartbeat Control" which purpose is to reduce calls and decrease the resource usage. So I set it up like this: http://prntscr.com/jjlcgj but see no improvement as well.

So I contacted the hosting provider again, they said "The process is called dovecot/ imap it if helps". Well, and now I have no idea what to do about it (I have no experience with this). Any ideas how to reduce RAM usage?

P.S., sometimes the website is up only because of cloudflare, cause some times when I try to login to wp-admin I get error 500.

RAM usage can be seen here: http://prntscr.com/jjl65b

**UPDATE:**

So I have paid extra to double resources, now 2gb of RAM is being used at 100%. I have even tried to rename all folders like public_html, mail folder, etc, but nothing helped... Any ideas?

Comment: How many concurrent visitors do you have? It sounds definitly like there is something going badly wrong on your server, if it is not too many. Do you have some endless loop in admin-ajax.php functions? XD

Comment: Max 5-10 visitors at the same time... This is how my admin-ajax.php looks like: https://pastebin.com/raw/sUizsuME
Unfortunately, I am good in coding so I can't tell if the code is good or bad... Do You have some insights in it?

Comment: Its not like the admin-ajax.php itself will be the problem, but requests sent to it. Have tried deactivating certain plugins? It could also be a problem with a mining script infection which happens very often nowadays.

Comment: Yes, I just deactivated all plugins but the problem remain 1gb RAM usage at 100%...

Comment: Also, I have renamed the admin-ajax.php but the resources usage still remain. I doubled resources, from 1gb to 2gb, but it is still at 100%...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using your server as a email host. Unless you are a trained SMTP engineer, that is usually a bad idea.

Offload your email server from your host and uninstall dovecot. Chances are that it's not configured properly and it is being used as a spam relay, or it's on some blacklists somewhere, so you will get non-delivery of messages.

Your server should be sending transactional emails through a transactional email provider, like Mailgun or SendGrid or Postmark. Your personal email at that domain should be going through a professional service like zoho.

Bigger companies can dedicate teams to making sure that the SMTP ports are configured properly and that they are not on blacklists.

Comment: Well sure I am not SMTP engineer. As I am on shared hosting - I doubt that I can uninstall devcot. About email usage: so if I have small bussines with the website and some email accounts on it - it is a bad idea..? Never thought about this.

Comment: If you can't uninstall dovecot, make sure you aren't using the `mail` command. Make sure WordPress isn't sending through `smtp` or `localhost`.

Set a plan in place that you migrate from shared hosting to a VPS. You can get starter VPS for the same or less monthly fees than shared hosting.

Comment: Oh man... it seems I am lack of knowledge on this. I never had VPS and I have no idea how to run website on it, because as I understand it is totally different environment especially when there are lots of choices of VPS servers.

But again... it seems weird to me... If I pay for webhosting, build up a very basic website and create ~15 email accounts in cpanel while only 5 of those are more actively used - can this be actually a problem?...

Comment: Before we tangent off too far about VPS, keep track of your original problem:`"The process admin-ajax.php and lots of emails are consuming all of the RAM"`. Setup a mailgun account and make sure your wordpress is sending through it instead of your host. Look at https://kinsta.com/blog/admin-ajax/ to see options for reducing ajax-admin.php use. In cpanel, routinely monitor your resources. You may find something you weren't expecting. Remember we all had to start somewhere, and some started before others.

Comment: Actually I do not send any emails over WP. The only emails that goes over WP are the emails generated to confirm the appointment for the client once the booking form is submitted... About the admin-ajax.php, I am looking into this. About monitoring resources: I use WP Server Stats plugin which shows information like this: http://prntscr.com/jjn1fo  
Maybe my php.ini settings is wrong? You can see it here (php 7.2): http://prntscr.com/jjn286

While my actual hosting resources were doubled and now is like this: http://prntscr.com/jjn2xx
I still get overload:http://prntscr.com/jjn35l

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: probably the easiest first step is to reinstall your plugins from source, just to make sure no one has added a backdoor or script hack.

Comment: the thing is, that I have previously renamed the whole plugins folder, so all plugins were deactivated, but the problem still remain there. The strangest part is that the next day, just like at this moment, there is no ram usage at all... so this is kind of mystery... the hosting provider said that the only way is to reset hosting package and rebuild the website from scratch, but as I already have renamed lots of folders of website and the problem still was there, I am almost sure that problem is not related with the WP website itself...

Comment: Some heinous script could have been long-term cycling in memory. By renaming the plugins folder, the script cycle was stopped when it tried to come up for air. Try reinstalling FROM SOURCE your plugins, and run (assuming you have terminal capabilities) a checksum on all your plugin files. Periodically check the files against checksum. Make sure no one except you has write capabilities to your entire web root ( `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`).